# How to create the wizard-like ui in .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, wizard

I have to build the wizard-like ui since the operation should be done through 3 steps.

And in each step user will input some fields,then when he hit the next,I will check the current input,if valid,I will to to next wizard.

If there are input invalid,he will be left to current wizard.

That's to say,each time the user hit the next button,form will be submitted to server.

And when user hit the prev button,the content input before should be kept.

I do not have a good solution for this manner.

Any one can give me some suggestion?

Comment: Is there any problem about my post wihch cause the down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read a good article on how to use Wizard control in asp.net.
Please refer : http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2008/10/wizard-example-how-to-use-wizard.html